# Get specific text from a file with php

Tags: php

I'm making a cms for my last big school assignment, but I'm having a problem at the moment. I need the name of the database that is stored in another file. The php code of that file is:

```
<?php
try {
$db = new PDO ("mysql: host = localhost; dbname = name_that_I_need"; "user"; "pass");
$error = "false";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
$error = "true";
}
?>
```

i need the text: "name_that_I_need" (without quotes) how can i do this with php?

Comment: The question that comes up here is: Why? And why not just store it in a variable, constant or settings file in the first place?

Comment: Very stupid approach, but if you want it really, do it using regex.: `/dbname =(.*?)\"/g`. Then trim the result. Anyway! It is stupid, very!

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need ?> in the end of PHP file.
2. Usually people store database settings in a separate .php file as defines:

```php
<?php

define('DATABASE_HOST',  'localhost'); # database host address (you can also use direct ip declaration)
define('DATABASE_USER',  'root');      # database user
define('DATABASE_PASS',  '1234');      # database user password
define('DATABASE_NAME',  'name');      # database name
define('DATABASE_PORT',  '3306');      # database port
```

... it's better to edit your example .php file in this way and use only one source with this info in two different places.

Answer (score 0):

As user1597430 said, but it's better to put that kind of data in environment variable linux

```
<?php

define('DATABASE_HOST',  getenv('DATABASE_HOST')); # database host address (you can also use direct ip declaration)
define('DATABASE_USER',  getenv('DATABASE_USER')); # database user
define('DATABASE_PASS',  getenv('DATABASE_PASS')); # database user password
define('DATABASE_NAME',  getenv('DATABASE_NAME')); # database name
define('DATABASE_PORT',  getenv('DATABASE_PORT')); # database port
```

It should looks like that when you type `env` in your server

```
DATABASE_HOST=localhost
DATABASE_USER=user
DATABASE_PASS=password
DATABASE_NAME=mysql
DATABASE_PORT=3306
```

And so you could init your PDO like that :

```
new PDO ("mysql: host = " . DATABASE_HOST . "; dbname = ". DATABASE_NAME; DATABASE_USER; DATABASE_PASS)
```